# De Gruyter style table spreading over two text columns

Tags: tables, columns

I need to use [De Gruyter style](https://www.degruyter.com/page/production-for-authors) for a current work but I have trouble making a table that spreads over two text columns.

Usually, you can add an asterisk to the table environment, so that it it `\begin{table*}` but this does not seem to work here.

Minimal Example:

```
\documentclass[USenglish,oneside,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[big]{dgruyter_NEW}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\percent}{\,\%\xspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\centering
\caption{A table for testing}
{\small
\begin{tabular}{lllrr}
\toprule
\textbf{Name} & \textbf{Value 1} & \textbf{Value 2} & \textbf{Number 1} & \textbf{Number 2}  \\
\midrule
something    &  something    &  something    &  11.87    &  8.88    \\
something    &  something    &  something    &  14.16    &  1.27    \\
something    &  something    &  something    &  4.01     &  0.06    \\
something   &   something very long &   something even longer   &   0.10    &   17.33    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

This table is positioned in the left column of the two column layout and overlaps with text in the right column.
As said before, using `table*` does not work and results in not displaying the table at all.
I also tried placing `\onecolumn` before the table and `\twocolumn` afterwards, but then the table is placed on a page, the rest of this page is blank and the text starts at the next page.

What I want it to look like is:

```
tableoverbothtextcolumns
tableoverbothtextcolumns
text..text    text..text
text..text    text..text
text..text    text..text
text..text    text..text
```

So, is there a way to display a table at the top of a page, being centered and spread over both columns?

Thank you for any hints and comments!

Comment: What is the `dgruyter_NEW` .sty file?

Comment: Thanks for your comment and sorry for that missing file! It is the style file required for De Gruyter publishing. I added the link in the post, but here again: https://www.degruyter.com/page/production-for-authors
I also uploaded the sty file here: https://goo.gl/ewTfNe

Comment: In my experiment, `table*` works.

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with the rest of my .tex file. When I use `\table*` the compiler states: `Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \end{table*}` at the line with `\end{table*}`.I'll look into this.

Comment: You need to check that the example as posted demonstrates the error (also firefoxrefused to follow the link you gave as it said the https security was not set correctly) (the dgruyter.sty available from the publisher does not have _new in its name any more, I fetched a copy last week for a different question here.

Comment: Alright, it seems to be a conflict with the `subfigure` package. If added to the example above, it fails compiling. If I omit it in my original document, `table*` works fine (but the subfigures of course not).
I better try to re-arrange the figures to leave this package out, I guess.

Comment: The `subfigure` package is obsolete; I suggest `\usepackate[caption=false]{subfig}`