# Can't compile a journal's template

Tags: compiling

I need to use the dgruter's template for a journal article but it has become impossible to do it cause I'm constantly getting error messages, I only got it to compile after using % on \maketitle and \usepackage{microtype}. Do you have any ideas of what I might be doing wrong? you would get the documents I have here at "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1M58oZsWLdChsGWE-UV5R7Mnbs0zzum6z". The tex file I need to run is journal_article.

Comment: Most every journal creates a style file for their template. A quick search on this site finds the question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353790/de-gruyter-style-table-spreading-over-two-text-columns) where the first comment mentions a style file for De Gruyter. There's a link  to De Gruyter[here](https://www.degruyter.com/page/production-for-authors) which mentions the style file. Are you using the style file when you compile?

Comment: the style file is short a line or two as described in the readme they do not want to force the use of one engine based on the need to use their fonts which are not included so simply add as 2nd and 3rd line \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} will allow you to run a pdfLaTeX compilation but **do check why** their fonts are not available

Comment: Yes, I was using the dgruyter.sty file

Answer (score 1):

From the web site

> Please note that the fonts of DG Meta Science are necessary for the
> generation of the final print PDF via the templates. After conclusion
> of the publishing contract with De Gruyter you will receive the
> template package including the font DG Meta Science from your contact
> at De Gruyter.
>
> The De Gruyter bar is the key design element, and it is found on every
> page.   The size and position of the De Gruyter bar have been opti-
> mized for each text element. This ensures the visual uni- formity of
> each context. To simplify its use, the De Gruyter bar is part of the
> DG Meta Science typeface.
>
> Obligatory conditions:
>
> •Installation of the font files for the use in LaTeX!
> •Unzip the zip file on your pc.
> To get the package style file ‚dgruyter.sty‘ and the index style files ‚dgruyter.ist‘ and ‚dgruyter.xdy‘, execute: latex dgruyter.ins.  To get the documentation ‚dgruyter.pdf‘, execute: pdflatex dgruyter.dtx (compile ‚dgruyter.dtx‘ at least twice).
>
> NOTE You will receive the LaTeX package including the font files from
> your contact at De Gruyter.

They also reference the non-free [Minion Math](http://www.typoma.com/en/support_latex.html) fonts.

So its catch 22 sign a contract to produce a [production quality](https://www.degruyter.com/dg/page/production-for-authors/production) PDF !

Short term for PdfLaTeX you can start the preamble with these lines

```
\documentclass[openany,ngerman]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %add this line while building your draft for publication
\usepackage{lmodern} %also add this line while building your draft for publication
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %(only for the pdftex engine)
%\RequirePackage[no-math]{fontspec}[2017/03/31]%(only for the luatex or the xetex engine)
\usepackage[small,print]{dgruyter}
\usepackage{microtype}
```

Also beware of needing an ORCID ID and on [this page](https://www.degruyter.com/dg/page/production-for-authors/herstellung)
read the contents of **Guidelines for drafting manuscripts** and **Instructions for delivery of image data** images should be submitted in .eps format.

If you have further issues see any related answers e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=degruyter

Comment: I actually knew that, but thanks anyway...

Comment: Ok but I don't get any errors with those lines added and remove comments where you needed them it only errors if I don't add those two lines to both templates